# HDMI not working on Thinkpad x260

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi, thinkpad

I have a brand new install of Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.8.0) on a Lenovo Thinkpad X260.  When I plug in an HDMI cable I get no reaction from the external monitor and the computer.  In addition, running xrandr --verbose yields:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767 eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x4a) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 276mm x 155mm
Identifier: 0x43
Timestamp:  13848
Subpixel:   unknown
Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
Brightness: 1.0
Clones:    
CRTC:       0
CRTCs:      0 1 2
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
EDID: 
    00ffffffffffff0006af6d2200000000
    34190104a51c1078026ba79659579527
    1d4e5300000001010101010101010101
    010101010101143780b8703824401010
    3e00149b100000180000000f00000000
    00000000000000000020000000fe0041
    554f0a202020202020202020000000fe
    004231323548414e30322e32200a00a8
BACKLIGHT: 852 
    range: (0, 852)
Backlight: 852 
    range: (0, 852)
scaling mode: Full aspect 
    supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
    supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
audio: auto 
    supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
1920x1080 (0x4a) 141.000MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
    h: width  1920 start 1936 end 1952 total 2104 skew    0 clock  67.02KHz
    v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1097 total 1116           clock  60.05Hz
1920x1080 (0xc6) 138.500MHz +HSync -VSync
    h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.59KHz
    v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  59.93Hz
1680x1050 (0xc7) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
    v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
1680x1050 (0xc8) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
    h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
    v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
1600x1024 (0xc9) 103.125MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1600 start 1600 end 1656 total 1664 skew    0 clock  61.97KHz
    v: height 1024 start 1024 end 1029 total 1030           clock  60.17Hz
1400x1050 (0xca) 122.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1400 start 1488 end 1640 total 1880 skew    0 clock  64.89KHz
    v: height 1050 start 1052 end 1064 total 1082           clock  59.98Hz
1600x900 (0xcb) 118.997MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width  1600 start 1696 end 1864 total 2128 skew    0 clock  55.92KHz
    v: height  900 start  901 end  904 total  932           clock  60.00Hz
1280x1024 (0xcc) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
    v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
1440x900 (0xcd) 106.500MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width  1440 start 1520 end 1672 total 1904 skew    0 clock  55.93KHz
    v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  934           clock  59.89Hz
1280x960 (0xce) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1376 end 1488 total 1800 skew    0 clock  60.00KHz
    v: height  960 start  961 end  964 total 1000           clock  60.00Hz
1368x768 (0xcf) 85.860MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1584 total 1800 skew    0 clock  47.70KHz
    v: height  768 start  769 end  772 total  795           clock  60.00Hz
1360x768 (0xd0) 84.750MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
    v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.80Hz
1360x768 (0xd1) 72.000MHz +HSync -VSync
    h: width  1360 start 1408 end 1440 total 1520 skew    0 clock  47.37KHz
    v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock  59.96Hz
1152x864 (0xd2) 81.620MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1336 total 1520 skew    0 clock  53.70KHz
    v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  895           clock  60.00Hz
1280x720 (0xd3) 74.480MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width  1280 start 1336 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock  44.76KHz
    v: height  720 start  721 end  724 total  746           clock  60.00Hz
1024x768 (0xd4) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
    v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
1024x576 (0xd5) 46.995MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width  1024 start 1064 end 1168 total 1312 skew    0 clock  35.82KHz
    v: height  576 start  577 end  580 total  597           clock  60.00Hz
960x540 (0xd6) 40.784MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width   960 start  992 end 1088 total 1216 skew    0 clock  33.54KHz
    v: height  540 start  541 end  544 total  559           clock  60.00Hz
800x600 (0xd7) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
    v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
800x600 (0xd8) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
    h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
    v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
864x486 (0xd9) 32.901MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width   864 start  888 end  976 total 1088 skew    0 clock  30.24KHz
    v: height  486 start  487 end  490 total  504           clock  60.00Hz
640x480 (0xda) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
    h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
    v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
720x405 (0xdb) 22.176MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width   720 start  728 end  800 total  880 skew    0 clock  25.20KHz
    v: height  405 start  406 end  409 total  420           clock  60.00Hz
640x360 (0xdc) 17.187MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width   640 start  640 end  704 total  768 skew    0 clock  22.38KHz
    v: height  360 start  361 end  364 total  373           clock  60.00Hz
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Identifier: 0x44
Timestamp:  13848
Subpixel:   unknown
Clones:     HDMI1
CRTCs:      0 1 2
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
    supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
audio: auto 
    supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Identifier: 0x45
Timestamp:  13848
Subpixel:   unknown
Clones:     HDMI2
CRTCs:      0 1 2
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
    supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
audio: auto 
    supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Identifier: 0x46
Timestamp:  13848
Subpixel:   unknown
Clones:     DP1
CRTCs:      0 1 2
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
aspect ratio: Automatic 
    supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
    supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
audio: auto 
    supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Identifier: 0x47
Timestamp:  13848
Subpixel:   unknown
Clones:     DP2
CRTCs:      0 1 2
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter: 
aspect ratio: Automatic 
    supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
    supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
audio: auto 
    supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Identifier: 0x48
Timestamp:  13848
Subpixel:   no subpixels
Clones:    
CRTCs:      3
Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
            0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
           filter:
```

As you can see, my computer doesn't even see the HDMI as being connected.  I have tried to update drivers using Intel's update drivers program.  Other than that, I haven't found many other solutions online...

Comment: Aren't you using a display port to HDMI converter? It should be identified by the former if that's the case.

Comment: Not as far as I can tell.  The port looks like an HDMI one and it says HDMI next to it...